# Let $A$ be some interval and $f,g: A \to \mathbb R$. Assume $f,g$ are uniformly continuous and bounded. Prove/disprove $fg$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, continuity, uniform-continuity

**So I have sketched some proof and would love some feedback:**

We'll divide the proof into two parts:

First assume $A = (a,b)$ for some $a,b \in \mathbf R$.

$f,g$ are uniformly continuous in $A$ $\implies$

$\exists \lim_{x \to a^+} f(x), \lim_{x \to a^+} g(x), \lim_{x \to b^-} f(x), \lim_{x \to b^-} g(x)$

$\implies \exists \lim_{x \to a^+} fg(x), \lim_{x \to b^-} fg(x)$.

In addition, in the interval $(a,b)$: $f,g$ uniformly continuous $\implies$ $f,g$ are continuous.

Therefore, from arthimetics of continuous functions we have $fg$ is continuous in $[a,b]$.

From Cantor's theorem we have $fg$ continuous in a closed interval $\implies$ $fg$ is uniformly continuous in $A$.

Now Assume $a = \pm \infty$ and/or $b = \pm \infty$. Without loss of generality assume $a = +\infty$.

Now this is the part I'm having a hard time with. If $f,g$ weren't bounded then for example we could have $f(x)=x,\;g(x)=x+1,\;fg(x)=x^2+x$, where we know $f,g$ are uniformly continuous but $fg$ isn't.

So I understand that it $fg$ is uniformly continuous in this situation since $f,g$ are bounded but I'm having a hard time constructing a formal proof.

Comment: Let me help you with theorem:  If a function $f$ is uniformly continuous on a non-closed
set $A$, then it can be extended to $\overline{A} - A$, and, moreover, the only
in such a way that the resulting (extended) function defined on A
will be continuous on $\overline{A}$. Can you use it for your question?

Comment: $$\mathbf{Why\; type\; like\; this?}$$

Comment: Just use `**bold text**` for **bold text**.

Comment: $f(x)g(x)-f(c)g(c)=f(x)g(x)-f(c)g(x)+f(c)g(x)-f(c)g(c)=g(x)(f(x)-f(c))+f(c)(g(x)-g(c))$.